# Fuelphp oil admin template, model_user, find_by_username function

Tags: orm, model, admin, crud, fuelphp

I have used oil to generate an admin panel for my website. 
I have all the tables in my db, the website is working, I have enabled the orm and auth package but I have a problem during the login process.

The problematic controller/admin.php is at this point:

```
            if ($val->run())
        {
            $auth = Auth::instance();

            // check the credentials. This assumes that you have the previous table created
            if (Auth::check() or $auth->login(Input::post('email'), Input::post('password')))
            {
                // credentials ok, go right in
                if (Config::get('auth.driver', 'Simpleauth') == 'Ormauth')
                {
                    $current_user = Model\Auth_User::find_by_username(Auth::get_screen_name());
                }
                else
                {
                    $current_user = Model_User::find_by_username(Auth::get_screen_name());
                }


                Session::set_flash('success', e('Welcome, '.$current_user->username));
                Response::redirect('admin');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->template->set_global('login_error', 'Fail');
            }
        }
```

The function find_by_username in the call

```
  $current_user = Model_User::find_by_username(Auth::get_screen_name());
```

is not implemented and I assumed it must be in the model/user as follows:

```
class Model_User extends \Orm\Model
{
.......

    public static function find_by_username($username_given)
    {
        return Model_User::query()->where('username',$username_given)->get();

        //$escaped_username = \Fuel\Core\DB::escape($username_given);
        //return \Fuel\Core\DB::query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =$escaped_username")->execute();
    }
}
```

Now this returns something like this which is an Orm/Model_User object:

```
object(Model_User)#37 (11) {
   ["_is_new":protected]=>
   bool(false)
   ["_frozen":protected]=>
   bool(false)
   ["_sanitization_enabled":protected]=>
   bool(false)
   ["_data":protected]=>
   array(10) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "1"
     ["username"]=>
     string(5) "admin"
     ["password"]=>
     string(44) "UberSafePass"
     ["group"]=>
     string(3) "100"
     ["email"]=>
     string(16) "email@domain.com"
     ["last_login"]=>
     string(10) "1398875694"
     ["login_hash"]=>
     string(40) "9998e768da41821ae4c401359e797e1d96edfdb3"
     ["profile_fields"]=>
     string(6) "a:0:{}"
     ["created_at"]=>
     string(10) "1398868638"
     ["updated_at"]=>
     string(1) "0"
   }
   ["_custom_data":protected]=>
   array(0) {
   }
   ["_original":protected]=>
   array(10) {
     ["id"]=>
     string(1) "1"
     ["username"]=>
     string(5) "admin"
     ["password"]=>
     string(44) "VerySecretPassword"
     ["group"]=>
     string(3) "100"
     ["email"]=>
     string(16) "email@domain.com"
     ["last_login"]=>
     string(10) "1398875694"
     ["login_hash"]=>
     string(40) "9998e768da41821ae4c401359e797e1d96edfdb3"
     ["profile_fields"]=>
     string(6) "a:0:{}"
     ["created_at"]=>
     string(10) "1398868638"
     ["updated_at"]=>
     string(1) "0"
   }
   ["_data_relations":protected]=>
   array(0) {
   }
   ["_original_relations":protected]=>
   array(0) {
   }
   ["_reset_relations":protected]=>
   array(0) {
   }
   ["_view":protected]=>
   NULL
   ["_iterable":protected]=>
   array(0) {
   }
 }
```

But in controller/admin and some other parts of the code it is accessed like this:

```
Session::set_flash('success', e('Welcome, '.$current_user->username));
```

Sorry guys if this is a stupid question but since the Orm query method returns my data as I showed you and then the oil generated controller asks to access them like that, either I have done something stupid or I don't see something. 
I must add that I use Fuelphp 1.7.1
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Model_User class:
`$ oil r fromdb:model users --no-migration`